# Using a macro in function declaration in C

Tags: c

I have come across this code in the source of `CMake`:

https://fossies.org/windows/misc/cmake-3.17.0.zip/cmake-3.17.0/Utilities/cmzlib/compress.c

```
int ZEXPORT compress (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)
  Bytef *dest;
  uLongf *destLen;
  const Bytef *source;
  uLong sourceLen;
{
  return compress2(dest, destLen, source, sourceLen, Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);
}
```

Why is `ZEXPORT` used in the function, and how does it even compile?

If I change `ZEXPORT` to a random integer, like `5`:

```
int 5 compress (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen)
```

code won't even compile anymore.

Here are possible expansions:

```
define ZEXPORT WINAPI
define ZEXPORT   __declspec(dllexport)
```

Comment: What does `ZEXPORT` expand to?

Comment: How does `zlib.h` (which is `#include`d in your link) `#define ZEXPORT`? It is unlikely to be `#define ZEXPORT 5`

Comment: Add more info above.

Comment: So, it depends on the environment.

Comment: `ZEXPORT` is defined in [`zconf.h`](https://fossies.org/windows/misc/cmake-3.17.0.zip/cmake-3.17.0/Utilities/cmzlib/zconf.h) to a compiler-specific way to "export" functions.

Comment: So if make a new C file with `int __declspec(dllexport) main() { return 0; }` in linux and compile with gcc then it shouldn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Windows is used, this macro compiles to:

```
WINAPI
```

This is another macro that most likely expands to:

```
__stdcall
```

This makes the Microsoft compiler use a calling convention where the callee (rather than the caller) cleans up the stack.

On BEOS, this is defined to either:

```
__declspec(dllimport)
```

or:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

depending on whether the header file is being used in a user application or the library itself, respectively.

If any other operating system other than Windows or BEOS is used, then this macro is defined to nothing.